# JPA cascade problem: unable to delete items which are present in Set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is problem with deletion entity with related objects.

Error looks like it:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "notification" violates foreign key constraint "fk_notification_read_by_notification" on table "notification_read_by" Detail: Key (id)=(ce6e112c-bc73-4076-8491-93c453094253) is still referenced from table "notification_read_by".
```

There are table defitions: first table contains common information about notification itself, second is just marking "who read the notification".

First table:

```
@Data
@Entity
@FieldNameConstants
@Table(name = "notification")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Notification {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notification", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<NotificationReadBy> readNotifications = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

Second table:

```
@Data
@Entity
@FieldNameConstants
@Table(name = "notification_read_by")
public class NotificationReadBy {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "notification_id", nullable = false)
private Notification notification;

...
}
```

Method looks:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(String notificationId) {
    notificationRepository.deleteById(notificationId);
}
```

If I use `List<NotificationReadBy>` instead of `Set<NotificationReadBy>` it works fine.

The same behavior with enabling batching in hibernate settings. But with additional log:

```
HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 delete from notification_schema.notification where id='ce6e112c-bc73-4076-8491-93c453094253' was aborted: ERROR: update or delete on table "notification" violates foreign key constraint "fk_notification_read_by_notification" on table "notification_read_by"
Detail: Key (id)=(ce6e112c-bc73-4076-8491-93c453094253) is still referenced from table "notification_read_by".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.], SQL: delete from notification_schema.notification where id=?
Batch entry 0 delete from notification_schema.notification where id='ce6e112c-bc73-4076-8491-93c453094253' was aborted: ERROR: update or delete on table "notification" violates foreign key constraint "fk_notification_read_by_notification" on table "notification_read_by"
Detail: Key (id)=(ce6e112c-bc73-4076-8491-93c453094253) is still referenced from table "notification_read_by".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```